# Usage of SVN private repository with Jenkins instead of GIT

Tags: jenkins, svn, kubernetes

I am keeping all my code in SVN repository within my on-premise server. And also I am trying to implement the CI/CD pipeline for deploying my application. I am trying to use Kubernetes and Jenkins tools for implementing this. When I am exploring the implementation examples of CI/CD pipeline using Jenkins and Kubernetes, I am only seeing example with GIT repository and managing code commits using Webhooks.

Here my confusion is that, I am using SVN code repository. So How I can use my SVN code repository with Jenkins Pipeline Job ?  Do I need to install any additional plugin for SVN ? My requirement is that, when I am committing into my SVN code repository, Jenkins need to pull code from code repo and need to build project and need to deploy in test environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooks to trigger Jenkins from SVN are also possible. Or you can poll the repository for changes - the Jenkins SVN plugin supports both methods (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin). The examples you are looking at will have a step that does a build from the source code of a particular repo. You should be fine to swap git for SVN and still follow the examples as where and how the source is hosted is not normally related to how to use Jenkins to build and deploy it.